# How to find & retrieve matching study in PACS server using dcm4che?

Tags: dicom, dcm4che

I have a ClearCanvas archive server that has some DICOM studies, I would like to filter out some studies based on some tags,

I tried [findscu](https://github.com/dcm4che/dcm4che/blob/master/dcm4che-tool/dcm4che-tool-findscu/README.md) in [dcm4che3](https://github.com/dcm4che/dcm4che) to filter out studies by manufacturer name, Here is the query I tried to get studies that have manufacturer name as Philips

```
findscu.bat -c CCARCHIVE@192.1.1.1:105 -m "00080070=Philps*"
```

It does return some result but with empty manufacturer tag though all the study has manufacturer tag info. I tried different levels with -L argument, but no luck

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think manufacturer is a required query attribute (see part 4, section C.6 of the DICOM standard). That said, ClearCanvas may support it as a series level attribute (check the conformance statement). If so, you'll have to make a series level query. Add

```
-L SERIES
```

to your query. Lots more results, but may get you what you need.